# Get correct data attribute for the matched value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this following html

```
<div class="z-content" data-slug="aaa" data-content-url="some url 1"></div>
<div class="z-content" data-slug="bbb" data-content-url="some url 2"></div>
```

Now I have a hash in url and I get that part in this way.

```
var hash = location.href.substr(location.href.indexOf('#')+1);
```

Now I want to match that hash within the data sets I mentioned earlier and pick up the right data-content-url for that hash

```
var zcons = $('.z-content');
var zcon_array = [];

$.each(zcons, function (index, item) {       
    zcon_array.push( { value: $(item).data('slug')} );  
});

$.each(zcon_array, function(key, object) {
   if(object.value == hash)
   {
      alert($('.z-content').data('content-url'));  //But it picks up the first one ie 'some url 1' always 
   }
});
```

So even if the hash is bbb it goes to the first one.

Any help/hint is highly welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` as getter returns value of the first element in the set. You could use the current index for selecting the target element:

```
$('.z-content').eq(key) // use the index for filtering matching element
               .data('content-url');
```

But there is no need to create an array. You could use the `filter` method:

```
$('.z-content').filter('[data-slug="' + hash + '"]').data('content-url');
```

Note that `window.location.hash` returns the current `hash` property of document.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. It reduced to much lesser code. Thanks a lot.